# Validation stops working with hidden divs

Tags: c#, validation, webforms

I have created my own CRM system which works perfectly locally. However, when the project has been uploaded to our web server, I'm getting some weird errors. I'm hoping the one I'm describing here is the catalyst for the others.

There is a section that shows the next lead to call with a button to click so you can amend the lead contact details. It's a basic hide/show div toggle. I have validation on the textboxes in the "amendtext" div. However, the validation is completely ignored on the button click (I'm using a validation group). Remove the hide/show on the divs and the validation works fine.

[image]

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to arrange the divs and call the click to save event. I've edited out all the styling etc:

```
<div>
    <div id="viewtext" runat="server">
        <div class="leadaddress">
            <p><strong><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></strong></p>
            <p><asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /></p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <p><asp:Label ID="lblLeadTel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="leaddetailsbut">
            <p><asp:LinkButton ID="clickToAmend" runat="server" OnClick="clickToAmend_Click">Amend Address</asp:LinkButton></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="amendtext" runat="server">
        <p>
            <label>Company</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbLeadName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ID="CustomValidatorLeadName" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="tbLeadName"  
                OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorLeadName_ServerValidate"
                ValidateEmptyText="True"
                ValidationGroup="Lead">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label class="lblwidth80">Address 1</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAddress1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ID="CustomValidatorLeadAddress1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="tbAddress1"  
                OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorAddress1_ServerValidate"
                ValidateEmptyText="True"
                ValidationGroup="Lead">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label class="lblwidth80">Address 2</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAddress2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label class="lblwidth80">City</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbCity" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ID="CustomValidatorCity" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="tbCity"  
                OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorCity_ServerValidate"
                ValidateEmptyText="True"
                ValidationGroup="Lead">
            </asp:CustomValidator>

            <label>Postcode</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbPostcode" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator 
                ID="CustomValidatorPostcode" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="tbPostcode"  
                OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorPostcode_ServerValidate"
                ValidateEmptyText="True"
                ValidationGroup="Lead">
            </asp:CustomValidator>
        </p>

        <div>
            <p>
                <label>Telephone</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbTelephone"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CustomValidator 
                    ID="CustomValidatorTelephone" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tbTelephone"  
                    OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorTelephone_ServerValidate"
                    ValidateEmptyText="True"
                    ValidationGroup="Lead">
                </asp:CustomValidator>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="clickToSave" runat="server" OnClick="clickToSave_Click" ValidationGroup="Lead">Save Address</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    viewtext.Visible = true;  
    amendtext.Visible = false;  
}

protected void clickToAmend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    viewtext.Visible = false;      
    amendtext.Visible = true;
}    


protected void clcikToSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (this.Page.IsValid)
    {    
        //code to save the change...

        viewtext.Visible = true; 
        amendtext.Visible = false;   
    }       
}
```

I'm now starting to pull what little hair I have left...

Comment: Can you show us your client-side code? It may help pinpoint the issue.